# bamboo to install sotware

Tags: java, build, installation, bamboo

I am investigating a way to use bamboo to distribute complex environment changes to our dev teams. We have multiple teams which all need to have one environment, and each team contributes artifacts to that environment.

One of the issues is a specific third party softwares which needs to be installed on all the dev boxes, different for every team. This software version frequently changes and is a pain for every developer to go an setup as and when it changes. Is it possible to use bamboo and remote agents on each developer desktop to set up the initial  install and update of this software ?

Eg: Team A needs thirdpartysoftwareA(which changes constantly, team B needs thirdpartysoftwareB(which changes constantly) and both TeamA and TeamB need to to have the latest of thirdpartysoftwareA and thirdpartysoftwareB to be able to run their local builds and tests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bamboo could possibly do this, giving you a dashboard to kick of the job of installing the third party software on the machines, however Bamboo is more of the orchestration of the implementing script or install executable.

Your problem really sounds like you would use [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) for or some equivalent tool. This is specific software for describing how an environment should be set up and therefore is more of an implementation tool, with it's own language for describing users, files, and software packages etc. I've found it very useful for setting up my own environment (dev) to be exactly like the CI environment that runs the build.

You could always use Bamboo to run puppet however!

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the automatic deployment on the dev environment? That can be done pretty easy with bamboo.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have stated Bamboo can do this but have you looked at Attunity Replicate?

[Attunity Replicate](http://www.attunity.com/products/attunity-replicate)